# Javascript cloneNode - form state - dynamically selected list not copied

Tags: javascript, clonenode

Why are the form state of dynamically selected select lists not copied during cloneNode(true)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid black;background-color:pink">
  <p style="color:red;">A p element</p>
  <p style="color:green;">A p element</p>
  <p style="color:blue;">A p element</p>
  <input id="example" type="text" value="">

  <select id="my_select_list">
        <option value="" selected="">Select</option>
        <option value="B">Building</option>
        <option value="C">Contents</option>
        <option value="L" >Livestock</option>
  </select>


</div>

<p>Click the button to copy the div element above, including all its attributes and child elements, and append it to the document.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>


document.getElementById("my_select_list").selectedIndex = "2";
document.getElementById("example").value = "hi there";

function myFunction(){
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
    var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(cln);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect that the state of the select dynamically selected list was copied, as is the dynamically created form input text value?

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FABVNVTKIWN8

Comment: Likely ID confict

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/44983624/2147204