# Javascript clone node is not copying all values from cloned to new object

Tags: javascript, select, clone

```
<div class="container">
  <select class="btn" name="item">
    <option>Alpha</option>
    <option>Beta</option>
    <option>Gamma</option>
    <option>Theta</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="desc" name="desc">
</div>
```

In this example, element selected by default in the "select" dropdown is "Alpha". I want to clone the complete node with values. If i select a different value in the dropdown and enter some text in the input box, and then clone the node, only the text box value is cloned. The value of "select" dropdown in the new object remains the default (Alpha).

Why is the behavior of cloning different for "select" vs "input"?

```
var parent = document.querySelector(".container");
var button = parent.querySelector(".btn");
var textbox = parent.querySelector(".desc");

  > textbox.value
  < "some random text"
  > button.value
  < "Gamma"

var cloned = parent.cloneNode(true);
var childButton = cloned.querySelector(".btn");
var childTextbox = cloned.querySelector(".desc");

  > childTextbox.value
  < "some random text"
  > childButton.value
  < "Alpha"
```

Comment: @DeepakGang, there are 3 answers and you are supposed to accept any one of it.

Comment: @Sagar V. Thanks for reminding. I went to sleep after posting the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you change a selection, the state of the selection is stored in browser and the cloned node will never include the state of object/ element which is changed and/or stored by browser.

But for `input`, it is stored as a value of the attribute `value` and get cloned.

To clone a node with selected value,

#### You should detect the change event and add a `selected` attribute to it.

That is, add an event listener for `select` for `change` event.

Then in the callback function, set the attribute `selected` to that object by using

```
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected","");
```

Run the snippet below.

Select any value from the list and type something in the text box and click clone button.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".container");
var button = parent.querySelector(".btn");
var textbox = parent.querySelector(".desc");
console.log(button.value);
console.log(textbox.value);
function update(val){
  val.options[val.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected","");
  
}


function clone(){
  var cloned = parent.cloneNode(true);
  document.querySelector(".container-2").appendChild(cloned);
  var childButton = cloned.querySelector(".btn");
  var childTextbox = cloned.querySelector(".desc");
  console.log(button.value);
  console.log(textbox.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select class="btn" name="item" onchange="update(this);">
    <option>Alpha</option>
    <option>Beta</option>
    <option>Gamma</option>
    <option>Theta</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="desc" name="desc">
</div>
<button onclick="clone();">Clone</button>
<div class="container-2"></div>
```

Comment: `But for input, it is stored as a value of the attribute value and get cloned.` The value attribute of select also displays the selected value. What is different?

Comment: The value of select attribute will be kept only if there is a `selected` attribute present. But in browser, it is stored as state. the attribute not automatically added to the tag. @DeepakGarg

Comment: Thanks! I will cram it, but i still think that there has to be some better reason. Just imagine an ordinary object being cloned. Expectation would be that the new object would be an exact copy of the source, but here one property of the object, which is visible in the object, is not getting copied.

Comment: This is a great solution but if you select multiple options before cloning, multiple option tags will have that `selected` attribute on them. I solved this by looping over the options and removing the selected attribute if the index does not match the selectedIndex and setting it when it does.

Comment: @Peyman yes, spotted this caveat as well. Actually, it's a major flaw in this solution, users can and will select one option and then the other, in which case it would yield unexpected results. I just added the line `Array.from(el.options).forEach(option => option.removeAttribute('selected'));` to reset all options before setting the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

I use the getElementsByClass() method to get the interesting elements.Then via for loop I add an onchange event to clone the container.Note the at the end of the function i assign the value pf the parent select element to the cloned select elm.

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");


for(var i=0;i<button.length;i++){
button[i].onchange=function(){  
var cloned = parent[0].cloneNode(true);  
 console.log(cloned);
 document.body.appendChild(cloned);
  cloned.childNodes[1].value=this.value;
};
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select class="btn" name="item">
    <option>Alpha</option>
    <option>Beta</option>
    <option>Gamma</option>
    <option>Theta</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="desc" name="desc">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, i was looking for an explanation around the core problem. There must be something in the specification that is preventing the value to be cloned that i am missing

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a `<select>` does **not** copy the `value=` property on `<option>`s.

This happens because changing the attribute changes the state of the form control, but does not change the value of the HTML selected attribute of the element.
You can read more about it in [W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20011210/html.html#ID-70874476).

In your example, if you check the value of the `parent` node you will see that only that element will have the correct selected value and none of its clones.

Comment: What is the difference between "state of form control" and "value of HTML selected attribute" and why this reasoning is applicable only for the dropdown and not for the text box?

Comment: @DeepakGarg Create 2 "select" dropdowns with the same options, and choose a different option in each of them. Now Inspect their HTML from your browser. Do you see any difference? The answer would be no, because their selected value is not available in their HTML, but is stored internally in the state of that specific select dropdown element by the browser.

Comment: @user340674, i created 2 "select" dropdowns, and when inspected, i found that their values were different. `var button1 = parent.querySelector(".btn1");    ` `var button2 = parent.querySelector(".btn2");` button1.value was "Alpha" and button2.value was "Gamma" (that i had selected in the dropdown). Whatever is the reason for the value not getting copied over to new object, my question is why that reason is not applicable for text box?

Comment: @DeepakGarg That's not inspecting, that's using javascript to get their values - what I meant is use dev tools, and inspect their HTML. I'm not aware of the reason as to why it works for input and not for select element.